# Compare two dates with another two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I want to filter data from `SQL Server 2008 R2` using `FromDate` and `ToDate` with another 2 user input dates. I want query for that.
I want to filter data such a way that If user input 2 dates or any date in between of them lies in `FromDate` or 'ToDate' or in between date then it filters data.
**For i.e.**

```
 FromDate             ToDate
15-11-2014          20-11-2014
```

if user input dates are `11-11-2014` and `20-12-2014`. It means in between dates of this 2 dates lies in between `FromDate` and `ToDate` so it should return this record.
Now, if user input dates are `11-11-2014` and `14-11-2014`. It means in between dates of this 2 dates does not lie in between `FromDate` and `ToDate` so it should not return this record.
It must match given dates and as well as in between dates.

Answer (score 1):

you Can use this :

Where

DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, FromDate)) > '15-11-2014'

and

DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ToDate)) < '20-11-2014'

Answer (score 0):

please check the example, you just compare the parameter with both datetime column to extract the rows.

```
declare @table table(id int,frdt datetime, todt datetime)

insert into @table values (1,GETDATE()-20, GETDATE()-19)
,(1,GETDATE()-9, GETDATE()-8)
,(1,GETDATE()+20, GETDATE()+18)
,(1,GETDATE(), GETDATE()-1)
,(1,GETDATE()-20, GETDATE())
,(1,GETDATE()-10, GETDATE()+10 )

select * from @table

declare @frdt datetime = null , @todt datetime = getdate()-10

select @frdt, @todt,* from @table
where
 (@frdt is null or @frdt between frdt and todt)
and
 (@todt is null or @todt between frdt and todt)

 select @frdt = GETDATE() , @todt = GETDATE()

 select @frdt, @todt,* from @table
where
 (@frdt is null or @frdt between frdt and todt)
 and 
 (@todt is null or @todt between frdt and todt)
```

Comment: where you got the answer for this?

Comment: @MONEYMSN, I don't remember, but what do you want from me or us? Have any question or query,  then post your question or comment here with example.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question.

```
select 'a' A, CONVERT(date,'11/15/2014') FromDate, CONVERT(date, '11/20/2014') ToDate into #Temp

declare @frmDate date; 
declare @toDate date;

set @frmDate = Convert(date, '11/11/2014');
set @toDate = CONVERT(Date, '12/20/2014');

select * from #Temp where FromDate>=@frmDate and ToDate<=@toDate

set @frmDate = Convert(date, '11/11/2014');
set @toDate = CONVERT(Date, '11/14/2014');

select * from #Temp where FromDate>=@frmDate and ToDate<=@toDate
```

Hope fully it help you :)

Comment: this is not the thing im looking for. please read my post properly.

Comment: Are you expecting 1 input or 2 from user? @CSAT.

Comment: think that there is one row with id and 2 dates. and i want to compare it based on user input dates. and it should fulfill requirements as per details in post.

Comment: I still don't get it. Sorry @CSAT :(